# Calculating $\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}f(x)$

Tags: limits

Let $f(x)$ be a continuous function which satisfies $\displaystyle f(x^2+1) = \frac{x^2}{f(2^x)-1}$ and $f(x)>0\forall x \in \Bbb R$

then find $\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow 1}f(x)$.

$\bf{Attempt:}$ put $x=0$ in $\displaystyle f(x^2+1) = \frac{x^2}{f(2^x)-1}$

$\displaystyle f(1) = \frac{0}{f(1)-1}$ so $f(1)(f(1)-1) =0$ so $f(1)=0$

could someone help me to solve it , also please explain me is i am correct or not.

Comment: The very last assertion seems unjustified, indeed, false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got $$f(1)(f(1)-1)=0$$

So this implies $f(1)=0$ $\color{red}{\text{or}} $ $f(1)=1$. But since we've $f(x) >0 \; \forall x $, we can conclude that $f(1)=1$, and since $f$ is continuous, we can say that $$\lim_{x \to 1} f(x)=1$$

Comment: If $f(1)=1$ then the given equation is ill defined, right?

Comment: @ZacharySelk Yes, I think it should be written as $$f(x^2+1)=\frac{x^2}{f(2^x)-1} \; \forall x \in \Bbb R-\{0\}$$